# Jhipster ERROR! The entity generator doesn't support reactive apps with databases of type sql at the moment

Tags: jhipster

I can not create entity using  `>jhipster entity book`.
 Jhipster version is 6.9.1

#### The error log

```
INFO! Using JHipster version installed locally in current project's node_modules
INFO! Executing jhipster:entity book
INFO! Options: from-cli: true
ERROR! The entity generator doesn't support reactive apps with databases of type sql at the moment
Error: The entity generator doesn't support reactive apps with databases of type sql at the moment
   at EntityGenerator.error (C:\Users\metin.bulak\Desktop\jh\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\generator-base.js:1590:15)
   at EntityGenerator.validateReactiveCompatibility (C:\Users\metin.bulak\Desktop\jh\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\entity\index.js:240:26)
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\metin.bulak\Desktop\jh\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\index.js:893:25)
   at C:\Users\metin.bulak\Desktop\jh\node_modules\run-async\index.js:49:25
   at new Promise (<anonymous>)
   at C:\Users\metin.bulak\Desktop\jh\node_modules\run-async\index.js:26:19
   at runLoop.add.once.once (C:\Users\metin.bulak\Desktop\jh\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\index.js:894:11)
   at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've chosen to generate a reactive app with Spring WebFlux and so you can't use SQL databases because JDBC is blocking and R2DBC is not yet supported by JHipster.

So you have 2 choices: generate a non reactive app and use SQL database or generate a reactive app and use a noSQL database (MongoDB, Cassandra, Couchbase).

Comment: If you want to follow work being done, see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/11742